# Поменять местами только содержимое 2-х тегов в xml (c# winforms)

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Неправильно заносят данные и получается вот так.
Есть XML в котором много тегов, среди которых эти 2 `<name>` и `<description>`.
Если структура XML важна, то попробую сейчас воспроизвести.

```
<name>молочно-кислый продукт</name>
<description>Кефир</description>
```

Как бы поменять местами содержимое тегов чтобы получилось так? и сохранить файл

```
<name>Кефир</name>
<description>молочно-кислый продукт</description>
```

Я конечно попробую просто переименовать теги, но пока не знаю вдруг это повлияет на дальнейшую обработку xmlя.
Что скажете?

Comment: Не поменяет, конечно, если обработка производится _правильно_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для поиска тегов можно использовать XPath. Например, если в [xml](http://pastebin.com/ahyVj10G) есть несколько тегов offer и надо найти тот, в котором есть тег `<categoryId>64</categoryId>`, то пишем такой XPath: `"//offer[categoryId/text()='64']"`

```
// #r "System.Xml.Linq"
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

class Xml {
    static void Update(XElement x) {
        foreach (var n in x.Descendants("name")) {
            var d = n.Parent.Element("description");
            var v = n.Value;
            n.Value = d.Value;
            d.Value = v;
        }
    }
    static void Process(IEnumerable<string> cats, XElement file) {
        foreach (var cat in cats.Distinct()) {
           var xs = file.XPathSelectElements("//offer[categoryId/text()='" + cat + "']");
           foreach(var x in xs.ToList()) 
               Update(x);
        }
    }
    public static XElement ProcessFile(string cats, string file, int skipFileLines) {
        var xml = String.Concat(System.IO.File.ReadLines(file).Skip(skipFileLines));
        var x = XElement.Parse(xml);
        Process(File.ReadLines(cats).ToList(), x);
        return x;
    }
}
```

---

```cs
var root = @"C:\Temp\";
var x = Xml.ProcessFile(root+"cats.txt", root+"file.xml", 1);
x.Save(root + "file.new.xml");
```

тут в Xml.ProcessFile передается 1 - чтобы при загрузке [xml](http://pastebin.com/ahyVj10G) пропустить строку `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf8"?>`, т.к. в ней ошибка - `utf8`, а должно быть `utf-8`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34820/discussion-on-answer-by-stack-----2----xml).

Answer (score 2):

```
// #r "System.Xml.Linq"
using System.Xml.Linq;

var xml = @"<name>молочно-кислый продукт</name>
            <description>Кефир</description>";
var x = XElement.Parse("<r>" + xml + "</r>");
var n = x.Element("name");
var d = x.Element("description");
var s = new XElement(n.Name, d.Value) + "\n" + new XElement(d.Name, n.Value);
```

Результат

```
<name>Кефир</name>
<description>молочно-кислый продукт</description>
```

Comment: Ой, а пожалуйста с загрузкой файла подскажите... типа file.xml и в нем уже все меняется

Comment: @Андрей _"с загрузкой файла подскажите... типа file.xml и в нем уже все меняется"_ -- а что в файле? просто две строки? если нет, то добавьте точный пример в вопрос.

Comment: @Андрей а что делать с результатом? записывать в тот же файл?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. С результатом да, поменять и сохранить.

Comment: @Андрей добавил еще один ответ. для файлов.

Answer (score 2):

file.xml должен быть сохранен в кодировке utf-8

```
<data>
  <item>
    <name>молочно-кислый продукт</name>
    <description>Кефир</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Молоко полезно</name>
    <description>Молоко</description>
  </item>
</data>
```

---

```cs
// #r "System.Xml.Linq"
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

var path = @"C:\Temp\";
var x = XElement.Load(path+"file.xml");

foreach(var n in x.Descendants("name")) {
    var d = n.Parent.Element("description");
    var v = n.Value;
    n.Value = d.Value;
    d.Value = v;
}
x.Save(path+"file.new.xml");
MessageBox.Show("Готово!");
```

Результат

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <item>
    <name>Кефир</name>
    <description>молочно-кислый продукт</description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>Молоко</name>
    <description>Молоко полезно</description>
  </item>
</data>
```

Comment: Ругается что-то на n.Value = d.Value; (Для создания экземпляра объекта восп зарезервированным словом new). Тегов <name> и <description> много их бы в цикле перебрать все

Comment: Разобрался почему ругалось, оказывается от порядка тегов зависит. Ой и если не затруднит, то сохранение результата в новый файл например file.new.xml", чтобы проверить замены

Comment: В XML несколько тегов для последовательной замены, но почему-то делает 1 замену и выход. Не понимаю. Может имеет смысл прикрутить то, что эти теги находятся между тегами <item></item>?

Comment: @Андрей _"В XML несколько тегов для последовательной замены"_ -- скиньте пример xml на pastebin.com

Comment: Готово. http://pastebin.com/TmgqDiSy

Comment: @Андрей _"Готово. pastebin.com/TmgqDiSy"_ -- проверил. после выполнения кода, содержимое name переносится в description и наоборот. т.е. все работает как надо. а то, что name стоит ниже чем description, то это не имеет значения при чтении тегов.

Comment: Ура! Работает. Не ожидал, что эта замена будет за 1 секунду, немного другая замена длится 15 минут. Ой, а еще можно вас попросить помочь сделать замену по условию в определенных категориях <categoryId>, которые перечислить как бы  6488, 5, 77, 26

Comment: @Андрей _"сделать замену по условию в определенных категориях <categoryId>, которые перечислить как бы 6488, 5, 77, 26"_ -- непонятно. в file.xml есть <categoryId>6488</categoryId>, и что надо сделать?

Comment: Каждый товар расположен между <offer></offer>, мы заменяем <name> и <description> которые находятся в <offer> так (<offer><name></name><description></description></offer>) еще в <offer> находится <categoryId>6488</categoryId> так (<offer><categoryId>6488</categoryId><name></name><description></description></offer>). Заменить при условии по перечисленным категориям categoryId=6488, 72, 166... (категории вручную добавлять в код). В НЕ перечисленных категориях не заменять

Comment: @Андрей т.е. нужен отдельный файл (cats.txt), в котором есть строки с числами, например: 6488, 72, 166, и т.д. Если одно из чисел указано в <categoryId>, то в этом <offer> надо делать замену name <-> description. а если categoryId не указан в cats.txt, то замену делать не надо. так?

Comment: @Андрей а все теги offer находятся в одном большом file.xml, или в отдельных файлах, например: file1.xml, file2.xml, file3.xml, и т.д.?

Comment: По поводу cats.txt и списка категорий абсолютно правильно. По поводу тега offer с содержимым, то они перечислены последовательно один за другим в теге <offerS> вот пример http://pastebin.com/ahyVj10G

Comment: @Андрей _"вот пример pastebin.com/ahyVj10G"_ -- ок. завтра напишу.

Comment: @Андрей добавил [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485404/196972)

Answer (score 1):

Если содержимое `name` длиннее содержимого `description`, то метод [Update](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485404/196972) можно заменить следущим:

```
static void Update(XElement x) {
    Func<string, string> txt = s => 
        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, @"[\s\r\n]", "");
    foreach (var n in x.Descendants("name")) {
        var d = n.Parent.Element("description");
        if(txt(n.Value).Length > txt(d.Value).Length) {
           var v = n.Value;
           n.Value = d.Value;
           d.Value = v;
        }
    }
}
```